# One php array with some values for some indexs

Tags: php, arrays

I wanna create an array or a function n php with something like this:
for index between 1-20 returns "type 1"
for index between 20-25 returns "type 2"
for index between 25-35 returns "type 1"
for index between 35-40 returns "type 3"
for index between 40-60 retusn "type 2".

How can I do this?
For example id 1, id 22, id 50 can be type 1, but also id 2, id 23, id 51 are type 2.

I've tried this:

```
function getSkinType($id) {
    $skins = array(
        0,13,40,46,47,59,60,72,73,76,82,83,84,85,90,91,93,98,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112, 113,114,115,116,120,121,123,124,125,126,127,128,141,147,150,163,164,165,166,169,170,173,174,175,177,181,185,186,187,189,191,193,194,192,195,203,204,216,219,221,223,228,233,240,258,259,263,269,270,271,272,290,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,3 => "premium",
        2,7,9,11,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,18,23,24,25,28,29,30,32,33,34,35,36,41,43,44,45,48,51,52,57,58,63,64,66,67,69,88,92,95,96,97,100,101,122,131,133,138,139,140,142,143,148,154,155,156,167,171,172, 176,179,180,182,183, 184,188,190,201,202,206,214,215,222,224,225,226,227,234,238,247,248,249,250,251,252 => "normal",
        1,12,27,31,37,50,56,78,79,129,134,135,136,137,152,153,157,158,159,160,161,162,196,200,212 => "default"
    );
    return $skins[$id];
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear... When you say index 1-20. Do you mean the actual index or just values within that range?

Comment: I just wanna make something like a case 1,5,10: return "type 1" but with an array. Values in that range.

Comment: indentation and double space

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to simply make use of an index in the `$kins` array to represent the category. This could be passed into the function itself. For example, if you wanted to retrieve the `82` skin (at index `10` of the first category), you could use **[the following](https://3v4l.org/U25cC)**:

```
<?php

function getSkinType($category, $id) {
$skins = array(
    [0,13,40,46,47,59,60,72,73,76,82,83,84,85,90,91,93,98,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112, 113,114,115,116,120,121,123,124,125,126,127,128,141,147,150,163,164,165,166,169,170,173,174,175,177,181,185,186,187,189,191,193,194,192,195,203,204,216,219,221,223,228,233,240,258,259,263,269,270,271,272,290,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,3],
    [2,7,9,11,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,18,23,24,25,28,29,30,32,33,34,35,36,41,43,44,45,48,51,52,57,58,63,64,66,67,69,88,92,95,96,97,100,101,122,131,133,138,139,140,142,143,148,154,155,156,167,171,172,176,179,180,182,183, 184,188,190,201,202,206,214,215,222,224,225,226,227,234,238,247,248,249,250,251,252],
    [1,12,27,31,37,50,56,78,79,129,134,135,136,137,152,153,157,158,159,160,161,162,196,200,212]
);
    return $skins[$category][$id];
}

echo getSkinType(0, 10); // 82
```

In the above, category `0` corresponds to premium, `1` corresponds to `normal`, and `2` corresponds to `default`. If you wanted, you could set up variables for these and use the variables instead.

An alternative approach would be to use associative arrays rather than a category index, but that accomplishes essentially the same thing.

Comment: I think I didn't explained good. For example I have the ID 13 and I wanna know from what category is.
Something like getType($id) and this function to returns type of id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getSkinType($id) {
     $grouping = [
         'type 1' => [1, 13, 20, 25, 35], // [ ids ]
         'type 2' => [20, 25],
         'type 3' => [35, 40],
     ];

     foreach($grouping as $type => $range) {
         if (in_array($id, $range))  {
              return $type;
         }
     }

     return 'Type not found'; // default text here
}


echo getSkinType(13); // "type 1"
```

Comment: I think I didn't explained good. For example I have the ID 13 and I wanna know from what category is. Something like getType($id) and this function to returns type of id.

Comment: Yes this function would return the type. Have you tried it out?

Comment: Yes but for example I don't have a specific range, type 1 cand be 1,3,5 and type 2 can be 2,4,6.
Something like for id 1 or 3 or 5 return type 1, for id 2 or 4 or 6, like a case statement but i don't want to use case statement.

Comment: It has been updated to just check for the value, rather than use range.